# Measuring high voltage low current using a resistor and measuring the amps

Tags: current, high-voltage, multimeter

Is it possible to measure a voltage beyond what your multimeter is capable of measuring by measuring the amps providing you know the resistance? Just wondering if the voltage would still harm the meter.

Comment: How high are we talking about? Why not setup a resistive divider? (Also take into account the breakdown voltage of the resistors themselves, in which case you can use many in series).

Comment: Were talking around 2K VAC.

Comment: If you can accept some small error, get a cheap TekPower TP7040 ( https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0006GD7NU ) which already does 1000 VAC at \$9\frac{\textrm{k}\Omega}{\textrm{V}}\$; \$9\:\textrm{M}\Omega\$ input resistance at the \$1000\:\textrm{V}\$ setting. Add four \$2.2\:\textrm{M}\Omega\$ resistors in series into the plastic body of one of your probes. (Four because they usually stand off \$200\:\textrm{V}\$ each.) You really want them to be \$9\:\textrm{M}\Omega\$, but the slight added error is probably okay. The meter already has 4% error spec; another few % may be fine.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I think I will just build a voltage divider.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful.  - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163537)

Answer (score 1):

Meter specs tend tend to use 250v or 500 V rated parts. Exceeding these ratings by some margin may result is catastrophic failure to other parts when an arc bypasses the part.

There are 10:1 to 1000:1 probes rated to higher specs  which must be observe/chosen.

Using high voltage rated resistors you can make a voltage R divider for DC and for AC use high voltage rated capacitors to make a C divider.
[image] (not to scale)  $1 rated for 6.1kV

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6rYNy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you know the resistance of the meter you can add resistance to increase the voltage range. if the meter has 1M resistance on the 1000v range adding 9 more 1000V rated 1M resistors in series would allow measurement of up-to 10KV,  2kV in would read 200V after the modification.  but if you need to be safe, buy a proper high-voltage probe, don't try to build your own.